# onScroll of Android's ListView is not called

Tags: android-listview

I'm new to Android and Java.
I created a custom ListView as follows:

```
public class CustomEndlessListView extends ListView implements
        OnScrollListener, android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, IReceiver {
```

and then I clicked the 'Add unimplemented methods' option on Eclipse.

This result in the following method:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onScroll !!!!!");
}
```

with no @Override annotation.
If I manually add the @Override annotation I get :

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - implements android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener.onScroll
>     - The method onScroll(AbsListView, int, int, int) of type CustomEndlessListView must override a superclass       method

When I run the application (without the @Override annotation) this method (onScroll) is never called. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must register for scroll events by calling the setOnScrollListener.  Since you have implemented the OnScrollListener interface in your ListView subclass (which is not the only possibility) you can try something like the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_layout);
        CustomEndlessListView lv = new CustomEndlessListView(this);
        lv.setOnScrollListener(lv);
        setListAdapter(lv);
    }
}
```

Alternately you might register for the events in your CustomEndlessListView constructor:

```
public CustomEndlessListView(Context context) {
    // ....
    setOnScrollListener(this);
    // ....
}
```